# How do I write test class for an OpportunityContactRole that has a loockup field for contacts?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, test-setup

the situation is as follows, I have the opportunity, and inside it I have the Contact Roles and inside the contacts roles I have a lookup field that points out contacts, my test coverage is at 97% but, I would like to enrich my knowledge by discovering how test the scenario where this lookup field is filled.

Test Class:

```
Account conta = new Account();
        conta.Name = 'CONTA TESTE';
        conta.Tipo_de_Conta__c = 'Filial';
        insert conta;

        //CRIAR OPORTUNIDADE 
        oppPedVenda  = new Opportunity();
        oppPedVenda.Name         = 'teste Opp RC';
        oppPedVenda.StageName    = 'Qualificação';
        insert oppPedVenda;

        oppliPedVenda = new OpportunityLineItem();
        oppliPedVenda.OpportunityId = oppPedVenda.id;
        oppliPedVenda.PricebookEntryId = priceBookEntry1.id;
        oppliPedVenda.UnitPrice = 1.10;
        insert oppliPedVenda;
        
        //contato
        contact contato1 = new contact();
        contato1.FirstName ='Jõao1';
        contato1.LastName='Pessoa1';
        contato1.CPF__c='12345678912';
        contato1.Procurador_do_Contato__c=null;
        insert contato1;
        
        contact contato2 = new contact();
        contato2.FirstName ='Jõao2';
        contato2.LastName='Pessoa2';
        contato2.CPF__c='12345678912';
        insert contato2;

        contact contato3 = new contact();
        contato3.FirstName ='Jõao3';
        contato3.LastName='Pessoa3';
        contato3.CPF__c='12345678912';
        insert contato3;
        
        //OpportunityContactRole
        OpportunityContactRole oppcontrole1 = new OpportunityContactRole();     
        oppcontrole1.ContactId = contato1.id;
        oppcontrole1.OpportunityId = oppPedVenda.id;
        insert oppcontrole1;
        
        OpportunityContactRole oppcontrole2 = new OpportunityContactRole();     
        oppcontrole2.ContactId = contato2.id;
        oppcontrole2.OpportunityId = oppPedVenda.id;
        insert oppcontrole2;
     
        OpportunityContactRole oppcontrole3 = new OpportunityContactRole();     
        oppcontrole3.ContactId = contato3.id;
        oppcontrole3.OpportunityId = oppPedVenda.id;
        insert oppcontrole3;

        ProcessControl.ignoredByTrigger = false;

    @isTest static void test_NotaPromissoria() {
      
        Test.startTest();
        
        setupDados(Test.getStandardPricebookId());
        
        PageReference pageRef = Page.PDFNotaPromissoria;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('idOpp', String.valueOf(oppPedVenda.Id));
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        //DadosNotaPromissoriaController.getAvalist() testgetAvalist = new DadosNotaPromissoriaController.getAvalist();
        DadosNotaPromissoriaVF_VO testDadosNotaPromissoriaVF_VO = new DadosNotaPromissoriaVF_VO();
        DadosNotaPromissoriaController testControllerPDFNtPromissoria = new DadosNotaPromissoriaController();
        testControllerPDFNtPromissoria.getAvalist();
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }
```

I think to cover the scenario where the field `contact.Procurador_do_Contato__r.CPF__c`
be filled in, just create a contact where this field is filled in, but I don't know how to do that. Thank you who can help.

Comment: What is `Procurador_do_Contato__c`? a lookup field to contact on Contact? You'd want to create whatever record that lookup is first, set its `CPF__c` field to a value, and then create a contact that has the Id of the record you created first filled in for `Procurador_do_Contato__c`. Basically, exactly what you did to create `OpportunityLineItems` related to `Opportunity` & `PriceBookEntry`

Comment: So? "contato2.Procurador_do_Contato__c=contato1.Id;"  It worked! Thank you! Please put your comment in the answers so I can mark it as "the solution" @KrisGonçalves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no different than any lookup you may have in test scenarios.

1. You need to create the dependent record first (in this case, Contact 1)
2. Make sure to set `CPF__c` to have a value
3. Insert Contact 1
4. Then, you create the "next" record (a second contact)
5. Make sure to use the record Id from Contact 1 in the lookup field (`Procurador_do_Contato__r`)
6. Insert Contact 2

You did this a couple times in your existing code when creating `OpportunityLineItem` records against the `Opportunity` as well as when creating `OpportunityContactRole` - where you had to create an `Opportunity` and `Contact` first. You create the dependent data first, then use their Ids in the lookup fields for related records.

Comment: Thank you very much @KrisGonçalves